# how to only use alias in spring data elastic search

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring data search version is 4.1.15. I define entity class as below and use ElasticsearchRepository for CRUD and ElasticsearchOperations for customized query.
@Document(indexName = "my_index", createIndex = false)

Now I need to update to use alias only. Then there will be no change in the code when we need update index or reindex,

But I couldn't find any example to use alias only in spring data elastic search. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.